# Why when use sys.platform on Mac os it print "darwin"?

Tags: python, macos

In Python, when I type sys.platform on the Mac OS X the output is "darwin"? Why is this so?

Comment: Searching for "os x darwin" would've told you the answer...

Comment: There is actually an `aliased` parameter which you can pass to `platform.platform()` which is supposed to make it return a more "user-friendly" platform name (i.e. "OS X" vs. "Darwin"), but it [doesn't seem to work on OS X](http://bugs.python.org/issue7850).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Because the core of Mac OS X **is** [the Darwin OS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_%28operating_system%29).

Quoting from the linked WikiPedia page:

> Darwin forms the core set of components upon which Mac OS X and iOS are based.

Even the OS X platform itself reports itself as "Darwin" when you ask it:

```
$ uname
Darwin
```

Python merely uses that same platform identifier.

Answer (score 10):

To expand on the other answers: Darwin is the part of OS X that is the actual *operating system*, in a stricter sense of that term.

To give an analogy, Darwin would be the equivalent of Linux - or Linux and the GNU utilities - while Mac OS X would be the equivalent of Ubuntu or another distribution. I.e. a kernel, the basic userspace utilities, and a GUI layer and a bunch of "built-in" applications.